# Parallel.for() loop creating wrong thread IDs

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have developed a .net application using .net framework 4.0 where I have used parallel.for() loop for multi threading. I have used the following configuration:

1. Windows 7
2. IIS 7.0
3. Framework v4.0.30319

I have used ParallelOptions() class and the "MaxDegreeOfParallelism" property of this class is set to 5. I have logged the "Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId" in a log file to check whether 5 threads were created at the runtime. I have tested this application in two different environments. When the application is running at the environment where it has been developed it's creating 5 thread IDs. But while it's running at the other environment it's creating 6 or 7 threads IDs. The application is compiled at the 1st environment only. I have used the published version of the application to test at the 2nd environment.
Can anyone help me by informing why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Parallel.For` uses thread pool threads. The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` controls the maximum *concurrent* number of threads being used, not 5 particular threads - the thread pool is at liberty to process work on any of its threads, and `Parallel.For` makes sure only 5 are running at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because `Parallel.For()` uses *only* dynamic partitioner so passed in array could be partitioned on-the-fly and each partition is processed by a separate Task/Thread:

1. [MSDN: How to: Implement Dynamic Partitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997416.aspx)

   > Each time a partition calls MoveNext on the enumerator, the enumerator
   >   provides the partition with one list element. In the case of PLINQ and
   >   ForEach, the partition is a Task instance. Because requests are
   >   happening concurrently on multiple threads, access to the current
   >   index is synchronized.

   (I believe the same is true for `Parallel.For()`)
2. [MSDN: Custom Partitioners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425.aspx)

   > PLINQ supports a fixed number of partitions (although data may be
   >   dynamically reassigned to those partitions during run time for load
   >   balancing.). For and ForEach support only dynamic partitioning, which
   >   means that the number of partitions changes at run time. For more
   >   information, see Custom Partitioners for PLINQ and TPL.

   - [MSDN: Introduction to PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425.aspx)
   - [Does Parallel.For use one Task per iteration?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/26/9641563.aspx)